# A random variable whose mean is a random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Take $Y \sim Poisson(\lambda)$ and $\lambda$ being a random variable with the
distribution
$$f_{\lambda}(\lambda) = 80e^{-80\lambda}$$
for $\lambda$ with support $[0,\infty).$ I would like to find the unconditional
distribution of $Y^2$.

We see that
$$P(Y^2 = x) = P(Y = \pm \sqrt{x}) = P(Y = \sqrt{x}),$$
since $Y$ has the support of a Poisson random variable. That being
said, I am not sure how I might be accounting for the fact that
$\sqrt{x} \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\},$ based on the support of the Poisson
distribution. I then believe the next step is
$$P(Y = \sqrt{x}) = \int_0^{\infty} P(Y = \sqrt{x} | \lambda = k)f_{\lambda}(k)
dk,$$

Although I am not entirely sure. If this is the case then
$$= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{k^{\sqrt{x}} e^{-k}}{(\sqrt{x})!} (80 e^{-80 k}) dk.
$$
However, I am having difficulty figuring out how to integrate this, even with
Wolfram's suggestions. Any recommendations for this problem?

Comment: *Mathematica* gives your integral as:  $80 \cdot 81^{-\sqrt{x}-1}$.

Comment: What you are interested in is $Y^2$ and Rizky and Graham have already answered the question algebraically. I'd just like to point out that $Y$ is a Geometric distribution as follows: Poisson-Gamma mixture gives Negative Binomial distribution. Your distribution of $\lambda$ is Exponential, which is Gamma with shape parameter 1, reducing the Poisson-Gamma mixture to Poisson-Exponential mixture, namely from Negative Binomial down to its `basic unit' of Geometric distribution.  btw, Poisson-Gamma being Negative Binomial has a very nice interpretation in terms of S.P.P (Simple Poisson Process).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leave, for the moment, that $y=\surd x$ as it seems to be a distraction.

$$\mathsf P(Y=y) ~=~\dfrac{80}{y!}\int_0^\infty k^{y} e^{-81k}\operatorname d k ~=~ 80\cdot 81^{-1-y} \quad\Big[y\in\Bbb N\cup\{0\}\Big]$$

Then substituting back in. $$\mathsf P(X=x) = 80\cdot 81^{-1-\surd x}\quad\Big[\surd x\in\Bbb N\cup\{0\}\Big]$$

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier to calculate the unconditional distribution of $Y$ first.
\begin{eqnarray*}
\Pr(Y=y)&=&\int_0^\infty\Pr(Y=y|\lambda)f_\Lambda(\lambda)\mathrm{d}\lambda=\int_0^\infty\frac{\lambda^y e^{-\lambda}}{y!}80e^{-80\lambda}\mathrm{d}\lambda\\
        &=&\frac{80\Gamma(y+1)}{y!81^{y+1}}\int_0^\infty\frac{81^{y+1}}{\Gamma(y+1)}\lambda^{(y+1)-1}e^{-81\lambda}\mathrm{d}\lambda=\frac{80}{81^{y+1}}
\end{eqnarray*}
becuse the integrand is the pdf of $Gamma\left(y+1,\frac{1}{81}\right)$ and $\Gamma(y+1)=y!$.

Hence,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\Pr(Y^2=x)=\Pr(Y=\sqrt{x})=\frac{80}{81^{\sqrt{x}+1}}
\end{eqnarray*}